# JavaScript, JQuery, Download HTML element as an Image (Canvas to Image)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner to coding and I'm trying to allow the user to download an HTML element using Image to Canvas. So I've found the following script and it works. But the issue is it just generate the image on HTML instead of starting the actual download. Can you please tell me the steps to how to achieve this? Any assistance you can provide with this would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;

}

.dataset {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;


}

.widget {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: 20px !important;

    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #333;

    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;


    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;


    display: inline-block;
    page-break-after: always;

}

.widget .header p {
   padding: 10px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
   max-width: 360px;
}

.widget .header .title {
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-height: 36px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;

}

.widget .header:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.widget .header  .title.selected {
    border-color: cornflowerblue;
    background-color: #EEF;

}

.widget .content {
    padding: 5px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
}

.autolayout {
    display: inline-block;
}

.element {
    width: 360px;
}

.compact .content {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.compact .row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

.compact .cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

.compact .row.selected {
    background-color: #eee;
}



.toolbar {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 10px;
}

.toolbar .basis {
    min-width: 100px;
}

.btn {
    /*min-width: 60px;*/
}


.cell.value {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-wrap: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.cell.freq {
    width: 60px;
}

.cell.glyph {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
}


.element {

}
.element table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.element td {
    padding: 0px;

}

.element .selectable:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}


.element .stat {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-weigth: bold;
    color: darkgray;
}



.element .bar {
    height: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.bar-both {
    background-color: #0a67a3 !important;

}

.bar-fg {
    background-color: #3e97d1 !important;
}

.bar-bg {
    background-color: #ddd !important;
}

.selected .bar-fg {
    background-color: #FC0;
}

.selected .bar-both  {
    background-color:#FA0;
}

tr.selected {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.crosstab .selectable:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.crosstab tr.selected {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.crosstab .header p {
    max-width: 600px;
}


.crosstab td {
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-align: right;
}

.crosstab td.value {
  min-width: 60px;
  max-width: 240px;
  text-align: left;
}

.crosstab .cell {
    vertical-align: top;
}



.crosstab th.cell {
    max-width: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: normal;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.crosstab .n {
    color: darkgray;
}
.fieldlist {
}

.constraints {
    min-width:300px;
    padding: 10px;

    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;


}
.constraints table {
    width: 100%;

}

.sidenote {
  max-width:300px;
  padding: 0 10px 0px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.headnote {
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.info-block {
    /*border: 1px solid lightgrey;*/
    background-color: #eee;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;

    /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #9bc0cf, 0 0 0 3px #e0ebf0;*/
}

.menu-item {
}

.menu-item-value {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}

.gradient-blue {
    background: #b8e1fc; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b8e1fc), color-stop(10%, #a9d2f3), color-stop(25%, #90bae4), color-stop(37%, #90bcea), color-stop(50%, #90bff0), color-stop(51%, #6ba8e5), color-stop(83%, #a2daf5), color-stop(100%, #bdf3fd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#b8e1fc', endColorstr='#bdf3fd', GradientType=0); /* IE6-8 */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="widget" class="widget" field="AGE" roundby="20" description="Patient age, in years">
    <div class="header ng-scope">
      <div class="title ng-binding">AGE</div>
      <p class="ng-binding">Patient age, in years</p>
    </div>
    <div class="element ng-scope">
      <div ng-show="hasData()" class="content">
        <table ng-model="table" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
          <colgroup>
            <col/>
            <col width="60x"/>
            <col width="100px"/>
          </colgroup>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="cell value">Value</th>
              <th class="cell freq">Freq</th>
              <th class="cell value"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="0" class="selectable ng-scope">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="0 to 19" class="ng-scope ng-binding">0 to 19</span>
            </td>

            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">17.2%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 17.234468937875754%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr><tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="20" class="selectable ng-scope">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="20 to 39" class="ng-scope ng-binding">20 to 39</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">18.0%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 18.03607214428858%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort --><tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="40" class="selectable ng-scope">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="40 to 59" class="ng-scope ng-binding">40 to 59</span>
            </td>

            <!--<td >{{table.getRowPercent('current', rowKey) | percent}}</td>-->
            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">34.3%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <!--<div class="bar bar-both" style="width: {{(row.current.pct * 100)||2}}px; " ></div>-->
              <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 34.2685370741483%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort --><tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="60" class="selectable ng-scope">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="60 to 79" class="ng-scope ng-binding">60 to 79</span>
            </td>

            <!--<td >{{table.getRowPercent('current', rowKey) | percent}}</td>-->
            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">24.0%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <!--<div class="bar bar-both" style="width: {{(row.current.pct * 100)||2}}px; " ></div>-->
              <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 24.04809619238477%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort --><tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="80" class="selectable ng-scope">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="80 to 99" class="ng-scope ng-binding">80 to 99</span>
            </td>

            <!--<td >{{table.getRowPercent('current', rowKey) | percent}}</td>-->
            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">6.4%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <!--<div class="bar bar-both" style="width: {{(row.current.pct * 100)||2}}px; " ></div>-->
              <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 6.4128256513026045%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort -->
          <tr ng-show="getShowMean()" class="">
            <td class="stat">Mean</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">46.1</td>
          </tr>


          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>


    </div>
  <!-- ngRepeat: field in getChildren(field) -->
</span>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG"/>

<div id="img-out"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112321/how-to-save-canvas-as-png-image/11112370

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used html2canvas but looks like there are different approaches for displaying (appending to DOM) versus saving the image.

As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27068145/5670890), what happens if you try something like this?

```
$(function() { 
  $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
      html2canvas(document.body, {
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
              return Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
          }
      });
  })
});
```

Alternatively, you may want to try using a hidden anchor tag with the rendered image as the href source and trigger click on it. This is untested code but maybe something like this:

```
$(function() { 
  $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
      html2canvas(document.body, {
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
            const imgDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
            const aTag = document.createElement('a');
            aTag.href = imgDataUrl;
            aTag.style = "visibility:hidden";
            aTag.download = "DownloadedImageFileName";
            document.body.appendChild(aTag);
            aTag.click();
          }
      });
  })
});
```

Comment: `let` should be `const` as your variables are never reassigned.

Comment: Thank you. I went with the second option with a little adjustment. :D